# Unable to bind value to ng-model for select options in an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**HTML**

```
  <select class="form-control"
          ng-model="campaign.CampaignTypeId"
          ng-options="CampType.id as CampType.name for 
         CampType in CampaignTypeIds track by CampType.id" >
      <option value="">Select campaign type</option>
  </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $scope.CampaignTypeIds = [{ id: "1", name: "Location" }, { id: "2", name: "Brand" }];

 $scope.getSingleCampaignResponse = function (response) {//http get method gets the resposne
    $scope.campaign= response
}
```

In an event I am getting campaign object as a response and that object has   **CampaignTypeId:1**, but I cloud not able to bind **CampaignTypeId** to ng-model for select option

Comment: What happens when you manually set $scope.campaign.CampaignTypeId?  As far as I know, angular only sets watches on ng-model values themselves and not the parent objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is the ng-options you have to put it like this `ng-options="CampType as CampType.name for CampType in CampaignTypeIds track by CampType.id"`. You can see it working in this [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/HsiBxXwuVafhXjwIIqrE?p=preview). Also you can bind the ng-model to an object, like `ng-model="campaign"`.

The markup:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-model="campaign"
            ng-options="CampType as CampType.name for 
            CampType in CampaignTypeIds track by CampType.id" >
        <option value="">Select campaign type</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

And on the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.CampaignTypeIds = [{
      id: "1",
      name: "Location"
    }, {
      id: "2",
      name: "Brand"
    }];

    $scope.getSingleCampaignResponse = function(response) { 
        $scope.campaign = response; 
    }

    //simulating request
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.getSingleCampaignResponse({ id: "2" });
      // or if you want like this
      // $scope.getSingleCampaignResponse({ id: "2" , name : "brand"});
    }, 2000)
}]);
```

Note the timeout is simulating the request after 2 seconds.

Comment: [lhere](https://plnkr.co/edit/sMCmbHrXdbLhbjGs7Dkt?p=preview) here it is and works.

Comment: the ng-model  on the markup as to be `ng-model="campaign"` and not `ng-model="campaign.id"`

Comment: I am afraid it's not

Comment: @SriChatala did you see this? https://plnkr.co/edit/sMCmbHrXdbLhbjGs7Dkt?p=preview. Can you describe what is not working?

Comment: its working fine here https://plnkr.co/edit/aFqa4p?p=preview, if I applied same format, its not working, any way thanks for ur help

Comment: check this link, it shows exact problem that I have: https://plnkr.co/edit/aFqa4p?p=preview, issue solved